# bundle install gemspec error spree_social.gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, spree

In my app when I am running `bundle install`, I am getting below error.

> vendor/gems/spree_social/spree_social.gemspec
>   is not valid. Please fix this gemspec.
>   The validation error was 'spree_social-3.1.0.beta contains itself
>   (spree_social-3.1.0.beta.gem), check your files list'

I tried everything like removing the `Gemlock` and updating the gems. It didn't work.

Below is my `Gemfile`

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

   ruby '2.3.0'
   # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
   # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
   gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.5.0'
   # Use SCSS for stylesheets
   gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
   # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
   # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
   # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
   gem 'roo-xls'
   # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
   gem 'turbolinks'
   # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
   gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
   # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
   gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
   gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
   # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
   gem 'paperclip'
   # Use Unicorn as the app server
   # gem 'unicorn'
   gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
   # Use Capistrano for deployment
   # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

   group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a  debugger console
   gem 'byebug'
   gem 'sqlite3'
   end

  group :production do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a  debugger console
  gem 'pg'
 end

  group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
   gem 'spree_scaffold', github: 'freego/spree_scaffold'

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


  gem 'spree', '3.0.5'
  gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
  gem 'spree_wishlist' , :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_wishlist-2.2.0')
 gem 'spree_social',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_social')
 gem 'spree_gift_card',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_gift_card')
  gem 'stringex'
  gem 'spree_reviews',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_reviews')
  gem 'spree_auth_devise',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_auth_devise-3.0.6')
  gem 'spree_mail_settings',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_mail_settings')
  gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: 'master'
```

Anyone else faced this?

Thanks

Comment: could you add your `Gemfile` ??

Comment: Added the same in the question @AmolUdage

Comment: please check ` gem 'spree_social',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_social')
` I think there is something going wrong

Comment: I know there's something gooing wrong. But what is that thing is the question :-/

Comment: check your `spree_social` gem from vendor, is there file inside this gem called `spree_social.gem`??

Comment: why are you not using gem directly from remote ?
`gem 'spree_social', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_social', branch: '3-0-stable'`

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Could you pls. share the fix? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: I did sort of idiotic hack to get away with it. 

In the `Gemfile`, where you're giving the path, rename that file  `spree_social` to `spree_social1` and do the same under `/vendor/gems`, and then run bundle install. 

That's how it worked for me.


Logical solution will be to `fork` the repo and then use it via  `GIT` only

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But couldn't get the reason as the same setup worked on different machine ....

Comment: now the biggest pain will be come when you'll have ti push this to github or bitbucket. That's where you and the other collaborators will find difficulties. BTW what's the reason you're doing it this way and not via github repo?

have you made some change in the GEM and then saving it locally? I'd suggest you to fork the repo and clone from your own fork. This will not come and this way you'll get the future updates of the gem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your compiled .gem file is contained in the repository. I assume that this is because the gem is trying to package the `spree_social-3.1.0.beta.gem` file inside itself, and it doesn't like that. Try removing the .gem file from the repository and rerunning bundle install.

I am willing to bet that `File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_social'` points to a git repository, where `bundle install` will compile and install the gem each time you try to run it. My understanding is that when the gem is compiled in this way, it runs `` git ls-files -z`.split("\x0") `` on the git repository to get the list of files to put in the gem. Since the .gem file appears in the results, it tries to compile it into the gem, which causes it to fail.

I ran into this issue today, where my Gemfile was pulling a gem from a repository I published to Github, and `bundle install` kept failing until I removed the .gem file from the repository.